# Turning off id focus of browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

Is there a way of turning off the id focus off a browser?
So when I add something with a hashtag to a url like *google.com/#results* the browser automatically focuses the div with id results. So is there a way to turn that of?`

I for example have a website which is using the ids for a css statement. It's for a javascript free menu, but my problem is that the browser always switches focus when I click the menu

See there: http://emailsally.com/vlw/datenschutz.php -> the menu on the left site.

The solution should be javascript-free too!

Comment: "Turning it off" is as easy as not adding the hash, so why would there be an option to actually disable it ?

Comment: Cause im using the hash for another function

Comment: Use classes instead of ids.

Comment: But how can I refer to classes using css?

Comment: @Lithilion have you read some basic document about CSS? especially the CSS selector? In CSS, ID and Class can't replace each other, in some case you must use ID and in other cases you should use class.

Comment: `nav ul li#stellenausschreibungen:target a, nav ul li#stellenausschreibung:target > ul li a` this is my selector for the id. You can replace it with a class